# Does ARKit support text recognition?

Tags: ios, arkit

I want to develop an app that recognizes text using the camera, and displays an object based on that text using ARKit. 
For example, the camera "sees" a chair so the app should display a 3D object of a chair. Could this be done and if so, how?

Comment: Vision (part of CoreML) supports Text and also Face, Barcode, Objects recognition ...https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/

Comment: i want to know that which model of ML support text recognition

Comment: You don't need any Model ... You just need In Built Framework "Vision" ... You can find many tutorials by searching detect text with vision framework ...

Answer (score 1):

ARKit itself cannot do OCR.

In general doing OCR is possible but not trivial. Getting it to work in real time is also a challenge.

Eventually you will would need an OCR framework like [Tesseract](https://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios) or [Swift OCR](https://github.com/garnele007/SwiftOCR).

Comment: i know using OCR text recognition is possible but how integrate OCR to ARkit

Answer (score 1):

ARKit doesn't support text recognition.

Vision supports text detection, but it doesn't "know" what it is reading.

You need to use Vision to detect the text, and use CoreML to interpret it.

Comment: Thank you..so much

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/164213/coreml-and-vision-machine-learning-in-ios-11-tutorial  here they are use vision t as well as coreML but using this i,m not able to detect text

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you watching this WWDC session

[Text Recognition in Vision Framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/234/)

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: imageURL, options: [:])
let request = VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest { (request, error) in
 guard let observations = request.results as? [VNTextObservation] else { return }
}
request.reportCharacterBoxes = true
try? requestHandler.perform([request])
```

or

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: imageURL, options: [:])
let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
 guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else { return }

 for currentObservation in observations
 {
 let topCandidate = currentObservation.topCandidates(1)
 if let recognizedText = topCandidate.first {
 print(recognizedText.string)
 }
 }
}
request.recognitionLevel = .accurate
try? requestHandler.perform([request])
```